# Expression blend 4, go back to window after editing DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, windows, expression-blend

If I have a Xaml Window open, I can goto Resources in the right panel, and see all my DataTemplates. If I right click on one of them, I can select a data template, click edit, then graphically edit my template.

Now that is nice, but, **how do I go back to the Window containing the DataTemplate?** If I right-click the window in the right hand panel, I can select "view xaml", but there is no option or menu I can find that returns me to the main Window for graphical editing. Where is it?!?

Anyone know how to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhere in the bar above the design view if i remember correctly, it's a path in the hierarchy which you can go up.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Also in the `Objects and Timeline` toolbar there's an up arrow which brings you back.

[image: Screenshot 2]

*(Where it says `DataTemplate1 (ContentPresenter Template)`)*

Comment: Oh, I see. There is a tiny little arrow icon that does it. Because that is obvious..... Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's not, i also searched quite a bit the first time i edited templates in Blend.